# Sample matrix data and retrieve in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sample, sample-data

In *Matlab*, I want to sample data in such a way that to calculate the length of matrix, and for that, calculate its every `20th` row and stores in a array. That what I sampled my data.
`length(P)` for instance which is `251`.

Now, I want to check if the Original `P` index is equal to the sampled Matrix index (obviously the operation is in loop) then merge both same indexes, Which is:

```
[L]=[0];
for ii=1:length()
if P(ii,:)==  SP{ii}(ii,:) %SP is sample points array
L = [P(ii,:)=; SP{ii}(ii,:);];
end
end
```

**My Problem:**
I'm unable to sample the data in my accordance, i.e `SP= datasample(P,2);` and also, couldn't retrive the calculated `L` very well, may be facing problem of indexes, i.e

`if L~=0
 l=L(ii,:);
 end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data after 20th iterations, can be simply in `for-loop` instead of any built-in function, the code below showing some sketch for only one cell index.

```
kk = 0;
for ii=1:round(length(P{1})/30)
kk = kk+20;
L{ii} =P{1}(kk,:);
end
```